# How to make one word italic in legend in base R

Tags: r, plot, legend

I have this piece of code, I cant not crack. I want to make one word italic in my legend and use this in a loop. The line of code is in bold.

```
legend('top', paste(italic(increase$Gene[i]), increase$Sex[i], increase$Drug[i]), bty='n', text.font=2, cex=4.0)
```

This would be extremely helpful. So far online has not been helpful.

See attached code:

```
pdf(file= "/Users/cahighfi/Desktop/MaleCocaineConsumptionPlots_UbiInc.pdf", width = 30, height = 30);
par(mfrow = c(4, 4),     # 2x2 layout
      oma = c(2, 2, 0, 0), # two rows of text at the outer left and bottom margin
      mar = c(5, 5, 2, 1)+0.1, # space for one row of text at ticks and to separate plots
      mgp = c(2, 1, 0),    # axis label at 2 rows distance, tick labels at 1 row
      xpd = NA) 
x<-1:3
for (i in 1:nrow(increase)) {
  plot(x=c(1, 3), increase[i,2:3], type="o", col= "red1", ylim=c(-40,40), cex.main=3.0, ylab ="", xlab="", axes=F, lwd=8)
  axis(side=1, at=c(1,3), labels=c(1,3), cex.axis=3.0, font = 2)
  axis(side=2, cex.axis=3.0, font = 2)
  box()
  lines(x=c(1, 3), increase[i,4:5], type="o", col= "blue1", lwd=8)
  legend('top', paste(italic(increase$Gene[i]), increase$Sex[i], increase$Drug[i]), bty='n', text.font=2, cex=4.0)
  legend('bottom', paste("P", "=", increase$p.value_chng_pref[i]), text.font=4, cex=4.0, bty='n')
   mtext("Preference", side=2, line=3.25, cex=2.5, font = 2);
   mtext("Exposure", side=1, line=2, cex=2.5, font = 2);
 }
 dev.off()
 graphics.off()
```

Comment: how about `legend('top', legend=substitute(italic(x) ~ y ~ z, list(x=x[i], y=y[i], z=z[i])))` -- change x, y, z to your variables

Comment: Error: unexpected '=' in: legend('top', legend=substitute(italic(increase$Gene) ~ increase$Sex ~  increase$Drug, list(increase$Gene="

Comment: multiverse: that;s not quite what I suggested. Try this  `legend('top', legend=substitute(italic(x) ~ y ~ z, list(x=increase$Gene[i], y=increase$Sex[i], z=increase$Drug[i]))` . For more exact help you will need to make your example reproducible.